# finding probability function, bills and dice

Tags: probability

There are 2 white bills, and 4 green bills. We throw the dice, if it gives 6 - we take two bills, if it gives 1/2/3/4/5, we take one bill. X variable is the amount of white bills taken out. I need to find the probability function for X and draw the cumulative distribution function. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose we draw the bills at random from the 6 bills you describe.

$P(X = 2) = \frac{1}{6} \cdot \frac{\binom{2}{2}}{\binom{6}{2}}$, because in order to get two white bills, we need to throw a 6, and then take the 2 white bills out of the 6 we have as well, and we multiply them, as they are independent events.

$P(X = 1) = \frac{1}{6}\cdot P(X = 1 | \mbox{6 thrown}) + \frac{5}{6} \cdot P(X = 1| \mbox{1,2,3,4 or 5 thrown})$ by a standard formula.

$P(X = 1 | \mbox{6 thrown}) = \frac{\binom{2}{1}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{6}{2}}$, because we select 2 bills, and 1 one it is white, the other green.

$P(X = 1 | \mbox{1,2,3,4 or 5 thrown}) = \frac{2}{6}$ as we draw only one bill and it has to be white.

$P(X = 0) = 1 - P(X=2) - P(X= 1)$ as we only have 3 possible values.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  $X$ can take the values $0,1,2$.  You need to find the probability of each.  For $2$, you have to roll a $6$ and then take two white bills.  Can you find the chance of that?  For zero, you have a certain chance of drawing one bill, and it has to be green, plus another chance of drawing one bill, which then both have to be green.  Can you do that?  The chance of $1$ is what is left.  Then look up what a cumulative distribution function means and apply the definition.